# VBA: Insert content from clipboard in a certain file format at a certain position in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am looking for a vba-script that will paste the current content of my clipboard on a specifiable position (let's say on the top right corner outside the slide that is currently selected).
I would like the script to paste it as an .emf. However, if someone could explain to me how to manipulate the script for choosing the position and another paste ending that would be great.

### Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: What I finally would like to achieve is to take the inserted clipboard content and to make it left and bottom align to a shape that is already selected in Powerpoint and then to have the already existing shape deleted. So that for the user the procedure would be:
1. Copy e.g. a diagram from excel into the clipboard
2. Select a shape on a powerpoint slide
3. Run the script
4. Have the content pasted, left and bottom aligned and then have the older shape deleted

If someone knew a way of how do this that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modified version of the answer to your earlier question.  You can't control where something will be pasted, but you can get a reference to the shape when it's pasted and use that to move it where you want:

```
Dim oBackShape As Shape
Dim oFrontShape As Shape
Dim oSlide As Slide

' Now we'll assume that only one shape is selected:
Set oBackShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
' Get a reference to the slide that the shape is on
Set oSlide = oBackShape.Parent
' Paste the contents of the clipboard as EMF and
' get a reference to the new shape
Set oFrontShape = oSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)

With oFrontShape
    ' Left align them
    .Left = oBackShape.Left
    ' Bottom align them
    .Top = oBackShape.Top - (.Height - oBackShape.Height)
End With

oBackShape.Delete
```

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks a big, big bunch. This makes my daily work a lot less daunting and get's the important tasks at front.